# Attempting to update combo box updates table instead?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am a bit of an Access novice, but I'm slowly catching on. I am rebuilding a database at work, and I'm struggling with an odd issue in regards to updating combo boxes.

What I am trying to do, is separate each portion of our plant by complex and then by machine name. To do this, I am using two combo boxes; the first of which lists the various complexes, and the second which lists the various machines available to that complex. By selecting a complex, and then a machine, I would like to list all of the data associated with that specific machine.

The issue that I am having, however, is that upon attempting to update the machine combobox, one of the text boxes in my form (that I have set to locked) gets updated with the index of the complex that was selected. That index then replaces the name of the first entry in my complex table.

The VBA code being used to update the machine combobox is listed below. (Prior to incorporating this code into the header of a multiple items form, I had no issues whatsoever.)

```
Private Sub cboComplex_AfterUpdate()
Me.cboMachine.RowSource = "SELECT MachineName FROM" & _
                            "Machine WHERE ComplexID = " & Me.cboComplex & _
                            "ORDER BY MachineName"
Me.cboMachine = Me.cboMachine.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
The following link shows screenshots of what is occurring to help clarify.
[Screenshots](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8yTv76sp_ILSThFNG5VN2U4TWc&usp=sharing)

Comment: Is the text box bound to your table? Maybe you should create an unbound box and populate that? I'm trying to understand what you want to accomplish

Comment: When you select a complex, you want the second dropdown to just filter to the Machines of that complexID, and then use that machine and complex ID to populate your form's data?

Comment: Yes, at this time, the text box is bound to my table. It is currently bound because I was trying to figure out how the multiple items forms worked, but it would make sense as to why I would need to populate it. Yes, you are correct in regards to how I wish to populate my form as well. Sorry for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dancing along the lines of an answer and a comment, but my comment was getting long and I like formatting, so I'm posting it.

At a glance, you should use **unbound** controls for your filtering boxes (the machine and complex).

The record source for your form (assuming machine table data, you could tailor it to whatever you want) could be bound to something like :

`SELECT * FROM machine WHERE complexID = [Forms]![myForm]![cboComplex] AND Machine = [Forms]![myForm]![cboMachine]`

You could `form.requery` on update of those boxes.

Or you could have it more generic like `Select * FROM Machine` and just set your form's `Filter` property after update of your Machine combobox.

So in after update of your combo box (you could filter each one individually, or assume / require selections from each box), you can set a filter.

```
 Me.Filter = "Complex = """ & Me.cboComplex & """"
 me.filteron = true
```

These are just a couple of suggestions on how to implement this. As far as your filter boxes updating your table data, I'm assuming it's because you have them bound to your table :)

Comment: Okay, I'm understanding what you're saying, and I just about have it working. I just need to figure out how to use form.requery properly.

Comment: If you opted for my first suggestion, in the `after update` event for your second combo box (or first one), you could put `[Forms]![myForm].requery` and possibly `[Forms]![myForm].refresh`

Comment: No problem, glad you could figure it out.